# Firefox and Chrome rendering incorrectly

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, rendering

I have a website which in the past few days has stopped rendering correctly on Chrome and Firefox. The site code has not been updated at all which could have caused the error. It still renders correctly on IE and Edge.

The search box is an absolute element which should appear over the grey bar and the magnifying glass should appear within the search box.

It is difficult to show code as until a few days ago, it was functioning correctly.

[image: Image showing incorrect rendering]

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS

Comment: would a link to the site be better so you can see the error?

Comment: Better than nothing...

Comment: Cured this. Don't know why it suddenly changed though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if some css standards changed recently but the addition of a 'top: 0px' to the css seemed to fix this.